# Azure Cosmos DB / DocumentDB - With CMK: How to set default identity?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, azure-bicep

Trying to deploy using **BICEP**, but I get this error:

```
failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).

Status Message:
  At least one resource deployment operation failed.
  Please list deployment operations for details.
  (Code: DeploymentFailed)
  
 {
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Customer Managed Key and Continuous backup mode can only be enabled together with a valid User Assigned or System Assigned Managed Identity. Please set a User Assigned or System Assigned Identity as default identity and retry the request.
} (Code:BadRequest)
```

I am in fact, trying to set Customer Managed Keys, so looks like from the error, that I need to set a User Assigned Identity, as the default identity. I did something similar back when doing a regular SQL database, but not getting any success here. I have my User Managed Identity already created, and have the resource link ready.

From my Bicep code:

```
resource cosmos 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2023-04-15' = {
  
  ..
  
  identity: {
    type: identityType
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${cmkIdentityResourceId}' : {}
    }
  }
  
  properties: {
    keyVaultKeyUri: 'https://xx.vault.azure.net/keys/xx'
    defaultIdentity: 'FirstPartyIdentity'
    ..
  }
  
  ..
}
```

I have checked the documentation at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

It lists this property, which I tried to set in the code above:

```
defaultIdentity

The default identity for accessing key vault used in features like customer managed keys. The default identity needs to be explicitly set by the users. It can be "FirstPartyIdentity", "SystemAssignedIdentity" and more.
```

I am unsure what "and more" means, but I know it's not SystemAssigned, as I am using a User Assigned. In my previous SQL Server setup, I provided something similar:
`primaryUserAssignedIdentityId : cmkIdentityResourceId` .. But in that, it was the actual resource UI. In the documentation for Cosmos DB it suggests "FirstPartyIdentity" and "more"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really clear in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-customer-managed-keys?tabs=arm-template#using-a-managed-identity-in-the-azure-key-vault-access-policy) but when using user-assigned identity `defaultIdentity` should be:

```
{
  ...
  defaultIdentity: 'UserAssignedIdentity=<user-assigned identity resource-id>'
}
```

So in your case:

```
{
  ...
  defaultIdentity: 'UserAssignedIdentity=${cmkIdentityResourceId}'
}
```

Here is a full sample using KV RBAC.

`key-vault-role-assignment.bicep` module:

```
param keyVaultName string
param principalId string
param principalType string = 'ServicePrincipal'
param roleId string

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(subscription().subscriptionId, resourceGroup().name, keyVaultName, roleId, principalId)
  scope: keyVault
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleId)
    principalId: principalId
    principalType: principalType
  }
}
```

And `main.bicep` file:

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param keyVaultName string = 'thomastestkv476'
param identityName string = 'thomastes-cmk-identity'
param cmkcosmosDbKeyName string = 'my-cosmos-db-key'
param cosmosAccountName string = 'cosmosdbthomastest476'

// create a managed identity
resource identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = {
  name: identityName
  location: location
}

// create a key vault
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' = {
  name: keyVaultName
  location: location
  properties: {
    enableRbacAuthorization: true
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: true
    enablePurgeProtection: true // required when enabling CMK
    enableSoftDelete: true // required when enabling CMK
    softDeleteRetentionInDays: 90
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled' // require when enabling CMK
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
      bypass: 'AzureServices' // require when enabling CMK if firewall enable
    }
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'standard'
    }
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
  }
}

// create the cosmos db cmk key
resource cosmosCmkKey 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: cmkcosmosDbKeyName
  properties: {
    kty: 'RSA'
    keySize: 3072
    attributes: {
      enabled: true
      exportable: false
    }
  }
}

// grant kv crypo permission to the identity
module keyVaultRoleAssignment 'key-vault-role-assignment.bicep' = {
  name: '${identityName}-${keyVaultName}-rbac'
  params: {
    keyVaultName: keyVault.name
    principalId: identity.properties.principalId
    roleId: '12338af0-0e69-4776-bea7-57ae8d297424' // Key Vault Crypto User
  }
}

// create cosmos db once the role assignment is done
resource cosmosDb 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2023-11-15' = {
  dependsOn: [ keyVaultRoleAssignment ]
  name: cosmosAccountName
  location: location
  kind: 'GlobalDocumentDB'
  tags: {
    defaultExperience: 'Core (SQL)'
    'hidden-cosmos-mmspecial': ''
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${identity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    databaseAccountOfferType: 'Standard'
    keyVaultKeyUri: cosmosCmkKey.properties.keyUri // key uri to use
    defaultIdentity: 'UserAssignedIdentity=${identity.id}' // use user assigned identity
    locations: [
      {
        locationName: location
        failoverPriority: 0
      }
    ]
    backupPolicy: {
      type: 'Continuous'
      continuousModeProperties: {
        tier: 'Continuous7Days'
      }
    }
    minimalTlsVersion: 'Tls12'
    capabilities: [
      {
        name: 'EnableServerless'
      }
    ]
    enableFreeTier: false // already have a free tier in this subscription
    capacity: {
      totalThroughputLimit: 1000
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right, it's missing in the documentation, but your answer added the missing pieces. It worked straight up. Thanks Thomas.